# convert video to flv ffmpeg.exe

Tags: c#, asp.net, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert video to flv using ffmpeg. I have found an article [here](http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/270457-How-to-convert-any-video-format-to-flv-using-c-net.aspx) and did same but when i'm uploading video it's 0kb in flv format. about mp4 everything is alright.

I think problem is here

```
string imgargs = " -i \"" + outputPath + "\\" + fileName.Remove(fileName.IndexOf(".")) + ".flv" + "\" -f image2 -ss 1 -vframes 1 -s 280x200 -an \"" + imgpath + "\\" + fileName.Remove(fileName.IndexOf(".")) + ".jpg" + "\"";
ConvertNow(imgargs);
```

any idea how i can improve that?

**EDIT**

if i'll run 
`ffmpeg -i C:Users\NewUser\Desktop\MOV_1013.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -preset medium -crf 23 -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -q:a 5 C:Users\NewUser\Desktop\MOV_1013.flv`

in cmd it works.. but in visual studio

```
 string cmd = " -i " + inputPath + "\\" + fileName + " -vcodec libx264 -preset medium -crf 23 -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -q:a 5 " + outputPath + "\\" + fileName.Remove(fileName.IndexOf(".")) + ".flv";
        ConvertNow(cmd);
```

doesn't works..

Comment: Does the command line work if you run it manually in a console?

Comment: in console? i dont get it..

Comment: and what i should write there? it's c# code.. sorry I'm new about ffmpeg and maybe my question is too silly

Comment: Your c# code is passing a command line to ffmpeg? `ffmpeg -i blablabla` ?  copy that string and execute it in the console; see if there are any errors

Comment: https://scontent-a-fra.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/t31.0-8/10710216_819507081413992_938109221521477958_o.jpg

Comment: No, don't run *my* blablabla run *your* command (whatever is in `imgargs`)

Comment: yeah it works. it's converting now. ffmpeg -i C:Users\NewUser\Desktop\MOV_1013.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -preset medium -crf 23 -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -q:a 5 C:Users\NewUser\Desktop\MOV_1013.flv